# I am getting a syntax error in a very simple less than or equal to if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax-error

Sorry if I'm making a simple mistake but I really can't figure this out.
I need to create a change machine for my computer science class and I know I've used a less than or equal to statement, but for some reason its not working now.

```
Amount= float(input("What is the dollar amount?"))

Change = 0
q = 0
d = 0
n = 0
p = 0

while Amount > 0:
  if Amount >= .25:
    Q = Amount - .25
    q += 1
  elif Amount > .10 and <= .25:
    D = Amount - .10
    d += 1
  elif Amount > .05 and <= .10:
    N = Amount - .05
    n += 1
  elif Amount < .05:
    P = Amount - .01
    p += 1

print q
print d
print n
print p
```

Error:

```
    line 18
          elif Amount > .10 and <= .25
                         ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
elif Amount > .10 and Amount <= .25
```

Also it is good to say, for clear programming, you should create variables with lowercase.

Edit: zondo (in comments) is right; it would be better to do:

```
elif .10 < Amount <= .25
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use chain comparisons in python:

```
elif .10 < Amount <= .25:
```

But also you're not modifying the `Amount` inside loop, so it's going to be running very long.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need the `and` because if the condition before (`>= 0.25`, for example) isn't true, then you don't need to check it again (`< 0.25`, in that case) because you know it is false.

Your while loop will never stop because you never decrease the value of `Amount`.

So, change like so

```
while Amount > 0:
  if Amount >= .25:
    Amount -= .25
    q += 1
  elif Amount >= .10:
    Amount -= .10
    d += 1
  elif Amount >= .05:
    Amount -= .05
    n += 1
  else:
    Amount -= .01
    p += 1
```

There will also be no change since the `p` value will consume the remaining amount.